# String from boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket weird behaviour

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I am trying to implement an application that uses sockets in C++. I'm trying to read the string from the socket, but I'm having all sorts of issues. I can't get the string in the main function, but I can get it in the function. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    try {
        asio::io_context io_context;

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8080));

        tcp::socket socket(io_context);
        printf("Accepting...\n");
        acceptor.accept(socket);

        for (;;)
        {
            std::string message = read_(socket);
            printf("Message: %s\n", message);
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        printf(e.what());
    }
}

std::string read_(tcp::socket & socket) {
    asio::streambuf buf;
    asio::read_until( socket, buf, "\n" );
    const unsigned char* data = asio::buffer_cast<const unsigned char*>(buf.data());
    std::string result((char*)data);
    printf("Text: %s, and length: %d\n", result, result.length());
    printf("Text casted: %s\n", data);
    return result;
}
```

And this is the output after I send the string: "test" through the socket:

```
Accepting...
Text: ♀²w, and length: 6
Text casted: test

Message: ░■w
```

Comment: `printf` is an old C function, and have no clue about C++ objects like `std::string`. If you want to print output in C++ use `std::cout` (like any decent beginners book, tutorial or class should have taught you). I'm actually surprised that the compiler doesn't complain to you.

Comment: Use `printf("Text: %s, and length: %d\n", result.c_str(), result.length());)` or use `std::cout` as @Someprogrammerdude pointed out.

Comment: Thanks guys! I had no clue about that, I'm not that used with C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, as the others have pointed out, `printf` doesn't work with `std::string`. You can easily work around it, but it's perhaps a good idea to write C++ code:

```
std::cout << "Message: " << message << "\n";

// ...
std::cout << "Text: " << result << ", and length: " << result.length()
          << "\n";
std::cout << "Text casted: " << data << "\n";
```

Besides that, there are ... issues. You have a C-style cast from `unsigned char const*` to `char*`. C-style casts are dangerous, because they end up `reinterpret_cast`-ing. In this case you incorrectly (and unnecessarily) cast away `const`.

Why not just buffer_cast to the desired type anyways?

```
auto data = asio::buffer_cast<char const*>(buf.data());
std::string result(data);
```

Which brings us to the next problem: you're assuming the data be NUL-terminated **and** not containing any embedded NUL characters. Better is to use the return value from `asio::read_until` (that you ignored):

```
auto length = asio::read_until(socket, buf, "\n");

auto data = asio::buffer_cast<char const*>(buf.data());
std::string result(data, data + length);
```

That being said, I'm not convinced that you can use `streambuf` as-if contiguous without further preparation. Why not use the buffer iterators to make sure you don't misunderstand any of the implementation details:

```
asio::streambuf buf;
/*auto length =*/asio::read_until(socket, buf, "\n");

std::string const result(buffers_begin(buf.data()),
                         buffers_end(buf.data()));
```

Note that this immediately removes the "problem" of forgetting about the length.

### BONUS TIP

Why not read into a string anyways, saving the copies and complexity:

```
std::string result;
asio::read_until(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(result), "\n");
```

## FIXED

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a502f3854af63f6)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

std::string read_(tcp::socket& socket);

int main()
{
    try {
        asio::io_context io_context;

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, {{}, 6768});

        tcp::socket socket(io_context);
        std::cout << "Accepting...\n";
        acceptor.accept(socket);

        for (;;)
        {
            std::string message = read_(socket);
            std::cout << "Message: " << message << "\n";
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}

std::string read_(tcp::socket& socket)
{
    std::string result;
    asio::read_until(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(result), "\n");
    return result;
}
```

With

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, which software did you used to record the gif at the end of your answer?

Comment: @Human-Compiler OBS -> remux to mp4 -> `ffmpeg` to transcode to gif with framerate 5. (sometimes gifsicle to optimize the gif)

Comment: That was the problem as the comments pointed out, I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to C++

Answer (score 1):

printf does not take std::string as argument. Since, printf is not type safe and is a variadic function, that's the resaon its compiling and not giving any error. Passing std::string to it will be an undefined behaviour.

Either use std::cout or use c_str method of std::string.

Comment: This is the start of the problem indeed. I added a some concrete ideas/advice to help with the actual task in my answer.